# SWT OleClientSite: How to load XML file in Excel?

Tags: excel, swt, ole

I have an Excel file in OfficeML format, MyData.xls. Since I upgraded to Office 2007 from Office 2003 I get a warning message saying that the file content does not match the file extension. It seems that OfficeML now must have the extension 'xml'.

In my application I use OleClientSite to display the file in an OleFrame object. If I change the file extension to 'xml' then Excel is not started. If I leave the extension as 'xsl' then I get the above warning message.

How can I force the file with the 'xml' extension to be opened in the OleFrame using Excel?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to switch back to the 2003 format, which should not require any changes to your application.  To do this, open your file with the extension set to *.xls.  When prompted with the warning ("... do you want to open the file now?"), proceed to open (this is a warning to make sure you don't unintentionally open a macro-enabled file).  Once in Excel and the file is open, simply save it as *.xls.  This can be done by going to "Office Button / Save As / Excel 97-2003 Workbook".

Now, the harder solution will be upgrading your application to deal with the new OfficeML format.  I don't know about the component you're using, but it will likely still work for some of the binary parts in the new standard (most notably VBA projects), but you're going to have to unpack and start reading XML files.

If you haven't already done this, create a new Excel workbook, save it as *.xlsx (the 2007 format) and in Explorer, change its extension to *.zip.  Open it up and take a look around.  For more in-depth on the files, I would start digesting this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205.aspx).

Comment: Tim: the content is being generated programmatically and OfficeML is a nice (and easy) way to create Office docs. The security warning is worrying my users and I want to avoid that.

Comment: Ah, I see!  So, the question is what file is really being output from your app?  My hunch is that it is the older Office 2003 XML Spreadsheet format (*.xml).  Can you open your file in notepad? If so, what are the first few lines?  A 2003 XML file (with the *.xml ext) would open properly from explorer (as the opening app is defined in the XML as <?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>.  Can you verify this?

Comment: Tim: yes the <?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?> node is present

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how you're opening the file, but that node should dictate to the OS what app to open.  Can you use automation, create an XL app object and force Excel to open it (xlApp.Open(file)?  Ultimately you should consider updating your app to output to the new 2007 Open Office XML format.  There's an interesting post here at stackoverflow that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591463/convert-excel-2003-xml-file-to-excel-2003-xls-format

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something, but shouldn't you just use `.xslx` as your extension?  I'm assuming that by OfficeML, you're refering to [Office Open XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML).

Comment: I don't know - I've tried so many variations. I think though that xls and xlsx are binary formats and if I save a sheet in OfficeML Excel uses the 'xml' extension.

Comment: xlsx files are a bunch of xml files zipped up together, so it's kind of a mix between text and binary.

Comment: Josh: sure, but the issue is that I have OfficeML content and just giving that an xlsx file extension is going to cause that warning message I mentioned about the content not matching the file type. The warning is making my users worried about opening the file and I want to avoid it without having to create real xls or xlsx files.

Answer (score 1):

The `<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>` should be present in the XSL template used. 
The below link explains clearly how to include the processing instruction. I had to do something similar and it worked for me.

http://www.shareyourwork.org/roller/ralphsjavablog/entry/generating_excel_sheets_with_xslt